# Disallow one following character in single position

Tags: regex, vb.net

My current regex:

```
(>|<)\s*[0-9]+\s*(kW|mW|KW|MW|kw|mw)[^h]*.*
```

Input text that should match:

```
> 8000 kW
> 8000 kW h
> 8000 kWa
```

Input text that shouldn't match:

```
> 8000 kWh
```

The pattern is producing the correct results right now in all cases except that it still accepts the following "h". How can I repair this regex?

Comment: Try [`[><]\s*[0-9]+\s*(?:kW|mW|KW|MW|kw|mw)(?!h)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%3e%3c%5d%5cs*%5b0-9%5d%2b%5cs*%28%3f%3akW%7cmW%7cKW%7cMW%7ckw%7cmw%29%28%3f!h%29&i=%3e+8000+kW%0d%0a%3e+8000+kW+h%0d%0a%3e+8000+kWa%0d%0a%3e+8000+kWh). Are you using `Regex.IsMatch` to just check if the pattern matches a string partially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead in addition to case-insensitive flag being set for a shorter, much more cleaner regex:

```
(?i)[<>]\s*[0-9]+\s*([km]w)(?!h).*
```

Comment: If OP uses the regex inside `Regex.IsMatch`, the `.*` is redundant.

Comment: I'm not sure about that hypothesis.